# Installing ISOFix mounting points in Ford Focus

Tags: ford, focus, installation, seat

I have a Ford Focus Mk2 and I wanted to install the mounting points for ISOFIX car seats and I have the [needed part](http://www.fordonlineparts.co.uk/product/ISOfix_mounting_kit_Focus_-_1357238_F1357238-392) but where can I find the installation instructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does sound fairly typical that these things come with no instructions. Your car manual should have information on isofix, but failing that, I found the following information on a post by Phil on [www.focusowners.com](http://www.focusowners.com/home/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1001) - which seems like a forum you would want to look at for Ford Focus specifics. Have a read of the full post over there.

Key info from the post is:

- Use a large flat screwdriver to unlock the hinge near the door.
- Lift the seat up and try to move it out of the way.
- Prise the rubber plugs out of the isofix mounting holes.
- Screw the metal bracket in with the loops facing forward.
- Fit the seat hinge back in place and bang down to re-engage the latch.
- Put the seat back to it's normal position.

(my note - you will easily be able to identify the isofix mounting holes once the seat is up. The rubber plugs come out with the use of a screwdriver)

Comment: I can confirm that this works!

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to fit the brackets on the smaller seat, behind the drivers side (in a UK, right hand drive car).

For my late 2005 model Focus, Mark II I think, UK registration "XX54" there was nothing on the door side hinge to lever up with a screwdriver (as per many instructions out there), instead the back seats came out according to [these instructions](http://www.fordownersclub.com/forums/topic/38659-removing-rear-seats-mk-25-to-fit-isofix/) on the Focus Fanatics forum.

The rubber/plastic bungs for the threaded bolt holes are then obvious under the line of the rear seat back, and comparatively easy to remove with a screwdriver. The bolts for the Isofix bracket can then be fitted with a Torx bolt (T50):

[image: Isofix bracket in place in a Ford Focus Mk II]

Answer (score 3):

For fitting ISOFIX (LATCH in the US) to a European Mk2 Ford Focus (2005-2010) my steps were as follows.  Note that this is for a UK-registered vehicle with the single-split rear seat behind the driver.

No removal of seat belts or any other bolts should be required.

Disclaimer - this is my DIY attempt, I'm not a qualified mechanic so please only carry the work out if you're confident in your own abilities.

**Tools / parts required**

1. Ford part # 1357238 (1x ISOFIX mounting point, 2x Torx T50 bolts, 2x plastic guides)
2. Flat head screwdriver (to push clasp securing the seat)
3. Torx T50 head socket (to fit T50 bolts).

**Fitting**

1. Lift the lower section of the double-split rear seat cushion.
2. Release the upper section of the double-split rear seat cushion and pull down to reveal the hinge
3. Release the hinge clasp by pushing the securing metal clasp (painted white on my vehicle) with the flat head screwdriver towards the rear of the car.  This should pivot open and allow the rear seat upright portion to be removed.  Pull the double-split upright portion away from the (still fixed) single-split seat.
4. Locate and remove two rubber bungs to reveal the bracket mounting points.
5. Fit ISOFIX bracket with supplied T50 bolts.  You may wish to use thread-lock on the bolts.
6. Re-fit the seat cushions, closing the hinge clasp to secure the seat upright.
7. With the ISOFIX bracket now visible between the upper and lower seat cushions, optionally fit the two plastic guides.

Further to the above steps, I created [this video/slideshow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpQQQn0beVg) to show these steps involved in fitting the Ford ISOFIX bracket.